# Why my PrimeFaces upload tool dont work?

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I triying to use the primefaces upload tool( http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf ). I manage to display it correctly and it looks like it works. But when i go check the database it is empty.
Why it is not uploading? I am sure that the EJB's that accesses the database is well programmed.

Also i notice this message in the console when i go to the page that retrieves from the DB.

> SEVERE: line 1:61 no viable alternative at character ';'

i am not sure if that has something to do with it. I see no other errors.

My code for the Upload tool looks like this:

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{uploadController.handleFileUpload}"   
        allowTypes="*.txt;*.doc;*.pdf;" description="Text Documents"/>
```

This is the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class UploadController {

@EJB
private IFileUploaderEJB fileUploaderEJB;
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UploadController.class);

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    String fileName = event.getFile().getFileName();
    String contentType = event.getFile().getContentType();
    byte[] bytes = event.getFile().getContents();

    Garbage garbage = new Garbage();
    garbage.setFilename(fileName);
    garbage.setFile(bytes);
    garbage.setDescription("info about the file");
    garbage.setFileType(contentType);
    fileUploaderEJB.uploadGarbage(garbage);

    logger.info("Uploaded: {}", event.getFile().getFileName());

    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile()
            .getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

This is the EJB to DB access(Im sure this part work correctly):

```
@Stateless(name = "ejbs/FileUploaderEJB")
public class FileUploaderEJB implements IFileUploaderEJB {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;


public Garbage uploadGarbage(Garbage garbage) {
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");        

    garbage.setUploadDate(dateFormat.format(date));     


    em.persist(garbage);

    return garbage; 
}
```

}

Why the data is not being added to the database?

-------------------------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------------

```
private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    System.out.println("INSIDE THE METHOD!!!!");
    uploadedFile = event.getFile();
    String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(uploadedFile.getFileName());
    String contentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();
    byte[] bytes = uploadedFile.getContents();

    // Now you can save bytes in DB (and also content type?)
    Garbage garbage = new Garbage();
    garbage.setFilename(fileName);
    garbage.setFile(bytes);
    garbage.setDescription("info about the file");
    garbage.setFileType("File extension");
    fileUploaderEJB.uploadGarbage(garbage);

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
            null,
            new FacesMessage(String.format(
                    "File '%s' of type '%s' successfully uploaded!",
                    fileName, contentType)));
}
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>pages/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>        
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primefaces_resource/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 
    </web-app>
```

Comment: Did handleFileUpload() method get fired? If not, did u register PrimeFaces Upload Filter inside your web.xml? If you did register, can you post portion of your web.xml that display information about PrimeFaces Upload Filter? Also did you check the size of your `bytes` array?

Comment: 1-I checked and the method did not get fired. 2-I updated the last changes in my managed bean. 3- The upload filter is not in the web.xml (i dont know how that should look like) 4- I didnt check the size of the byte array but i ded some changes, i dont know is that enoght

Comment: I did it i just needed to register the filter i will post what i did.

Comment: Yup, that exactly what I was going to suggest you do. Best of luck :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to add this to my web.xml the source code was correct.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
        <param-value>/uploaded</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem, and I resolved it adding the jars in WEB-INF/lib:

- commons-io-2.2.jar
- commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar

and add the filter in web.xml:

```
<filter> 
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name> 
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class> 
</filter> 
<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name> 
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> 
</filter-mapping>
```

I hope it works for you!